# Not authenticating users PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to figure out why this code is not authenticating users, a wrong combination of username and password gives a user access. Where am I going wrong? Am still a newbie, any help? also, a suggestion on how to encrypt the password, MD5, SHA etc, which is best?

```
<form class="login-form" action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
    <button type="submit" name="login" value="login">login</button>
    <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create anaccount</a></p>
</form>
```

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    include_once("db.php");
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $id = ['id'];
    $db_password = $row['password'];
    if ($password == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "You have entered invalid credentials.";
    }
}
```

Comment: <?php
     session_start();

   
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  include_once("db.php");
 
  
  $username = stripslashes ($username);
  $password = stripslashes ($password);
   
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  $id = ['id'];
  
  $db_password = $row['password'];
  
  if($password == $password){
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
  else{
   
   echo "You have entered invalid credentials.";
  }
 }
?>

Answer (score 2):

*1st:* You are comparing the same value, which will give you always **true**.

```
if ($password == $password) {
```

change it to the db value:

```
if ($db_password == $password) {
```

*2nd*: what is?

```
$id = ['id'];
```

You probably meant:

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

*3rd:* **stop using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated and unsafe. Switch over to PDO or mysqli_*!**

Comment: thanks for the corrections, but still not validating users

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on values after each row and check what they return.

Comment: What does `$_POST` contain? Is the `login` set? How does the script get `$username = stripslashes($username);` values? Maybe they should be `stripslashes($_POST['username'])`? Same for password. All together, I think you need to hire someone to do this for you.

Comment: maybe i have missed a point somewhere. Am learning Php for now. This is my html form `  <form class="login-form" action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"/>
    <button type="submit" name="login" value="login">login</button>
    <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
  </form>`

Comment: Did you debug it? Are you seriously storing password in DB as plain text? Why don't you check for password directly in the query? As I said before, **you really need to hire someone to do this for you!** I'm sorry, but it seems you have no idea what you are doing, and that has nothing to do with php whatsoever.